# Why other functions listed in the dict are also called?

Tags: python

I am writing a script that comprises some functions and an arg will call related function.

I tried `{'a':1,'s':2}['a']` and it only returns `1`, so I designed the structure of main function:

```
def main(): 
    {
        'topic_list'  : topic_list(),
        'topic_create': topic_create(),
        'produce'     : produce(),
        'consume'     : consume()
    }[args.mode]
```

When I call first function by command `python3 my_script.py --mode 'topic_list'`, it is run as expected. 
However, when the first function finished, the second function started to run... Why could this happen?

Comment: You're calling them when you define the dictionary. If you just want to put them in a dictionary, don't put `()` after their names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the functions when you're assigning them, instead of assigning the actual functions themselves:

```
def main(): 
    {
        'topic_list'  : topic_list(), <-- calling here
        'topic_create': topic_create(), <-- calling
        'produce'     : produce(), <-- calling
        'consume'     : consume()   <-- calling
   }[args.mode]
```

Instead, call it after resolving which one to call:

```
def main(): 
    {
        'topic_list'  : topic_list, <-- just the reference
        'topic_create': topic_create,
        'produce'     : produce,
        'consume'     : consume
    }[args.mode]()
```

You probably want to add a check to see if the `args.mode` value is present in the dictionary as well - you can use something like `.get(args.mode, default_function_to_call)` instead of just `[args.mode]` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This look magical...`{dict}[index]` returns a string of function name, and you put a `()` and the function is called, why?! I tried  `args.mode()` but it says `'str' object is not callable`, what's the difference between them?

Comment: `{dict}[index]` does _not_ return a string of a function name. It returns an object that _is the actual function_. If it were a string, you'd have to do to `"topic_list"` - and not just `topic_list`. The `mode` parameter from the command line _is a string_ (which has the same name as your function - but that's just a coincidence) - and that _string_ is matched against the _key_ of the dictionary - which _is a string_. In the dictionary, the _string_ points to the _function_, and it's the _function object_ that's being called, not the actual string.